# how to edit the form with data from the models

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
Editrow = KEBReading.objects.get(id=id)
print Editrow.datetime_reading
event_full_datetime=datetime(Editrow.datetime_reading.year,
                             Editrow.datetime_reading.month,
                             Editrow.datetime_reading.day,  
                             Editrow.datetime_reading.hour, 
                             Editrow.datetime_reading.minute,  
                             Editrow.datetime_reading.second)
date = event_full_datetime.year, event_full_datetime.month, event_full_datetime.day
time = event_full_datetime.hour, event_full_datetime.minute
print date
print time

form = KEBReading_form(instance=Editrow)
```

in my models i have a datetime field. but in my forms i have a separate date and time field. but when i want to edit a row my variable Editrow has datetime value how do i populate the form with separate date and time while passing the instance(Editrow)

```
form = KEBReading_form(instance=Editrow)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should understand how to [use widgets for form fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#specifying-widgets). Then, just use [SplitDateTimeWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.SplitDateTimeWidget).